# Can I ask a question about how to organize source code? And where?

Tags: discussion, questions, site-recommendation

I asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8957128/setting-up-a-large-software-system-in-delphi) a while back on Stack Overflow which pertained specifically to organizing source code of a large legacy multi-project system, which did seem a good fit for Stack Overflow. However, I have a similar question, only pertaining to a general source code organization structure. I'd like to get input on various optimal ways to organize a folder structure which supports different program languages, different solutions and systems (unrelated to each other), component imports, etc. all from within one master folder hierarchy.

For example, I develop applications using Delphi, Visual Studio, Titanium, and with support of SQL Server (scripts), and within just Delphi alone I have large systems, small stand-alone applications, projects which involve other languages (such as C# and HTML), etc.

If I were to ask such a question, I know Stack Overflow would not be legitimate. However, would this work in programmers.stackexchange?

Comment: It might.  But I gotta be honest; these questions are a dime a dozen, and they're often closed as "primarily opinion-based" or "too broad."

Comment: @RobertHarvey which is why I haven't already asked it in SO - it would definitely be closed in an instant. But what about elsewhere? Would that be covered in CodeReview?

Comment: You can give it a shot on Programmers.  Try to be specific, though, and explain your attempts.

Comment: The main problem here is this: *"I'd like to get input on various optimal ways to..."* We don't really do those types of questions. The FAQ covers all of the reasons: they're like polls, every answer is equally valid, they're subjective and only invite debate, etc. Now, if you presented a specific organizational system in your question and asked about that, that would be more acceptable in my mind. Answers should not be able to present "various optimal ways", they need to discuss a *specific* way.

Comment: It's a fine line, like Robert says. You can walk it, and I encourage you to try, but I also encourage you to think carefully about how you word your question, keeping the [Help](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/asking) in mind.